# Create SQLite after deploying wavemaker project to phonegap

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, cordova

I created project inside wavemaker and deployed it to eclipse using phonegap.
I need to create SQLite database so I can storage data while there is no network connection on device,so I can sync it after with server database.
I'm unable to create SQLite db  inside wavemaker due to communication problem with hibernate (dialect).
My question is am I able and how, to create SQLite db after I deploy project to eclipse? 
I have found many topics on this but non of the solutions help.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not use hipersonic db? it's similar to sqlite and it's java native (it's also come bundled with wavemaker, you can choose to store the data in memory or a file)

http://hsqldb.org/

http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Dev/HSQLDB